# How to pass a JS function as object property to iOS

Tags: ios, javascriptcore, jsvalue

I have a `JSExport` protocol named `ChannelExport` with the method `- (void)sendRequest:(NSDictionary *)request withCallback:(JSValue *)callback;`. Calling this method from Javascript code works alright, like this:

```
channel.sendRequestWithCallback({'foo': 'bar'}, function(response) { ... });
```

In ObjC, I can access the values in the `request` dictionary and also call the `callback` function.

Now I'd like to change the interface to `- (void)sendRequest:(NSDictionary *)request`, passing the JS function as part of the `request` dictionary, like this:

```
channel.sendRequestWithCallback({
  'foo': 'bar'
  'callback': function(response) { ... }
});
```

In this case, when I try to call the `callback` function in ObjC, the app crashes. Apparently the `callback` object is not a `JSValue`, but instead an `NSDictionary` (to be more precise, an `__NSDictionaryM`). I was assuming that the JS function is correctly wrapped as `JSValue` in the same way as it is when passing it as a simple parameter.

Any hint why this is happening, and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `- (void)sendRequest:(NSDictionary *)request` signature to achieve your goal. If you define argument as `NSDictionary`, JavaScriptCore will recursively convert all objects in this dictionary to corresponding Objective-C objects. Use `- (void)sendRequest:(JSValue *)requestValue` instead:

```
- (void)sendRequest:(JSValue *)requestValue {
    JSValue *fooJSValue = [requestValue valueForProperty:@"foo"];
    NSString *bar = [fooJSValue isUndefined] ? nil : fooValue.toString;
    // use bar

    JSValue *callback = [requestValue valueForProperty:@"callback"];
    [callback callWithArguments:myArguments];
}
```